# How do I chain gateways on my LAN?

Tags: networking, gateway, m0n0wall

I installed m0n0wall in a virtualized environment, I have 10 PCs connected to a router ( 192.168.1.0/24) which connect them to the internet through PPPoE, the problem is that this router does not have a QoS so what I want to do is the following:

1. Let all the PCs get their IP from the Router and the default gateway
   will be m0n0wall.
2. The moon wall will have 2 interface (LAN 192.168.1.20) and (Wan
   192.168.1.21 and default gateway 192.168.1.1)
3. Now when any PC want to access the internet it should go through
   m0n0wall and then m0n0wall will forward the connection to the
   default gateway through the wan interface which is the PPPoE running
   on the router (192.168.1.1)

The big question is this scenario possible or not and what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following:

1. Enable DHCP in m0n0wall LAN interface.
2. LAN Subnet: `192.168.10.0`
3. M0n0wall IP in LAN Interface: `192.168.10.1`
4. Default Gateway for Desktop on LAN: `192.168.10.1`
5. Connect m0n0wall WAN to LAN port router with Static IP: `192.168.1.21`
6. Connect all PCs, the m0n0wall LAN Switch.

Comment: I'm not sure i understood what you wrote but both interfaces ( lan and wan) will on the same subnetwork and as for the dhcp thats not an issue for me what i want is that the PCs connect to the m0n0wall which in turn connect to the internet through its internal WAN interface to the gateway on the router ( ip address 192.168.1.1) to put it in another way i want to chain both gateways the m0n0wall and the router.

Comment: M0n0wall Both interfaces can not be on the same subnet.
It is convenient:

. - Internet -> Modem
. - Modem -> Router Wan
. - LAN Router -> m0n0wall Wan
. - M0n0wall LAN -> Switch for PCs.

Comment: can please illustrate why can't the two interfaces be on the same sub network.